# Firebase Storage randomly returns storage/canceled

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting an error stating that the upload was cancelled by the user and I'm getting three errors from a single upload in the console (all the same error  from firebase storage when uploading a file. I cannot see how, within the code that a cancellation is being made (assuming that since it stated that the its the being cancelled by the user then it is within the code.

```
  startUpload(event: FileList, item:string) {
    // The File object
    const file = event.item(0);
    console.log(item);

    // Client-side validation example
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') { 
      console.error('unsupported file type')
      return;
    }

    // The storage path
    const path = `test/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;

    // Totally optional metadata
    const customMetadata = { user: item };

    // The main task
    this.uploadStatus = 'inprogress';
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata })
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(path);

    // Progress monitoring
    this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
    this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(snap => {
        if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
          // Update firestore on completion
          this.db.collection('photos').add( { path, size: snap.totalBytes }); 
          this.uploadStatus = "finished";
        }
      }),
      finalize(()=>{
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        console.log("Final");
      })
    );

}
```

The full error from chrome console :
"storage/canceled"
code_
:
"storage/canceled"
message
:
"Firebase Storage: User canceled the upload/download."
message_
:
"Firebase Storage: User canceled the upload/download."
name
:
(...)
name_
:
"FirebaseError"
serverResponse
:
null
serverResponse_
:
null

Firebase storage : Showing some of the uploads working (even though I get the error) :
[image: Firebase Randomly works]

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this error myself:

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/canceled", message_: "Firebase Storage: User canceled the upload/download.", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

My original view

```
 <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" *ngIf="(uploadPercent | async) == 0" [value]="uploadPercent | async"></mat-progress-bar>
```

```
| async
```

was the culprit that was cancelling the observable.

Solution:

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="(uploadPercent$ | async); let uploadPercent">
            <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" *ngIf="uploadPercent !== 100" [value]="uploadPercent"></mat-progress-bar>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! Thanks. I was doing exactly the same thing.. hiding the progress bar when it reaches 100%.